# Do I need a transit visa to fly alone through Dublin (Ireland) to Philippines and back?

Tags: transit-visas, filipino-citizens, uk-residents, dub

I am a Filipina living in Northern Ireland (UK) and have a 'Residence card of a family member of a union citizen'.

Answer (score 3):

No you don't need a transit visa. Courtesy of [KLM](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm):

> / 14NOV16 / 2132 UTC
>
> National Philippines (PH)       /Residence United Kingdom (GB)
>   Embarkation United Kingdom (GB) /Transit Ireland (Rep.) (IE)
>   Destination Philippines (PH)
>   ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW
>
> Ireland (Rep.) (IE)
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a "Family Member" Residence Card issued by United Kingdom to a family member of an EEA national or national of Switzerland.
>   TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>
> Additional Information:
>   - Visitors holding passports containing a British inadmissible stamp could be refused entry.